# What is difference between Numeric and Integer types, and how I can use timestamp level type in Mondrian?

Tags: mondrian

While reading manual of Mondrian I found that it has not so much types including Integer and Numeric - what's difference between this types?

And how can I use timestamp level type?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Well, Integer type can contain **only whole numbers**, like 5 or 123.
Numeric type can contain **decimal numbers** like 15.39.

About the second question: I think you're asking about **Time dimensions**, not the Timestamp (which is **type**). In this case it's better to refer the *Mondrian documentation*:

http://mondrian.pentaho.com/documentation/schema.php#Time_dimensions

Comment: Thank you! Good answer! Unfortunately I can't vote up because don't have 15 reputation..